# How to render a node mixing functional component and html string?

Tags: vue.js

I've got a functional component which need to render a child component (functional too) and an html string sibling to him in the same node.

Following this piece of code:

```
const html = 'My<br>Value';
const ResponsiveLabel = render('span', { class: 'responsive-label' }, 'MyLabel:');

return render('div', { class: 'ui-cell' }, [ ResponsiveLabel, html ]);
```

It should render this html code:

```
<div class="ui-cell">
  <span class="responsive-label">MyLabel:</span>
  My<br>Value
</div>
```

In this case, `My<br>Value` will just be interpreted as text, `<br>` will be visible.

**My goal is to render the `ResponsiveLabel` and `const html` as html.**

To do it with CreateElement function, we have to use the prop. `domProps` like this:

```
render('any', { domProps: { innerHTML: html } });
```

Which will result as a well interpreted html string, and `<br>` will make a carriage return.

But i don't know how to render this html with ResponsiveLabel before...

**I can't do that**

```
const html = render(undefined, { domProps: { innerHTML: 'My<br>Value' } });
const ResponsiveLabel = render('span', { class: 'responsive-label' }, 'MyLabel:');

return render('div', { class: 'ui-cell' }, [ ResponsiveLabel, html ]);
```

**Or even**:

```
const ResponsiveLabel = render('span', { class: 'responsive-label' }, 'MyLabel:');

return render('div', {
    class: 'ui-cell',
    domProps: { innerHTML: 'My<br>Value' }
  }, [ ResponsiveLabel ]);
```

How can i reach my goal ?

EDIT: it seems not possible. If we use render function, we have to use a tag. So I need to use one for my html string.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to wrap your `html` in an element.  There's no way around it as far as I know.  The `tag` is a required parameter.  Then as you mentioned, feed the actual `html` string to `domProps`.  After that, it's just a matter of calling your render function (`h` in this case) on each of your children in the order you want (see the `uicell` component below.

```js
const html = 'My<br>Value';

Vue.component('yourhtml', {
  functional: true,
  render(h, context) {
    return h(
      'span',
       { domProps: { innerHTML: html } },
    )
  },
})

Vue.component('reslabel', {
  functional: true,
  render(h, context) {
    return h(
      'span',
      {
       class: 'responsive-label' 
      },
      'MyLabel',
    )
  },
})

Vue.component('uicell', {
  functional: true,
  render(h, context) {
    return h(
     'div',
      {
       class: 'ui-cell' 
      },
      [h('reslabel'), h('yourhtml')]
    );
  }
}),

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <uicell></uicell>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i could use a tag, but i wanted to not use one :/
If i write the html by myself, it's acceptable in a SFC or within template prop, it's ok.
It's unfortunate to not be able to do it with render function.
Do you know if and how i could render ResponsiveLabel first ? Because i could concat it with html string.

Comment: @David the components are rendered in the order that they are given to the children array.  The example I have provided renders `ResponsiveLabel` first.

Comment: Yes i understand. But i wished to not use a tag for the html string, that's why i wondering if i can render the ResponsiveLabel as html then concat it to my html string so i will be able to just set innerHTML. But anyway it is working like that but i've got a tag in too much :)